# How to repeat string that is generated using string.Format N times

Tags: c#

In C# I have a list:

```
List<string> ls = new List<string>();
ls.Add("IR");
ls.Add("FR"); // list dynamically generated
```

and a string:

```
string langs = "select lang = {0} ";
```

I want a result like this:

> select lang = IR or lang = FR

I found a way:

```
string result = string.Empty;
foreach (string lng in ls)
    result += string.Format(langs, lng) + "or ";
if (ls.Count > 0)
    result = result.Remove(result.Length - 3, 3);
```

but I think there is a better way. Any ideas?

Comment: You can "save" the "or" by adding it to the "langs" string... :) or you can iterate using a "for" loop, and then you know when you're in the last element, and don't add the "or and then remove it

Comment: You should not use string concatenation to bulid SQL queries. What if someone adds `' OR 1=1` into your `ls`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change the `langs` string to the simple beginning of the clause:

```
string langs = "select lang = ";

List<string> ls = new List<string>() {"IR", "FR"};
```

and then [String.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx) the elements separated by `" or lang = "`

```
string res = langs + string.Join(" or lang = ", ls);
```

the output is:

> select lang = IR or lang = FR

Answer (score 2):

Only a single row is needed. `Join` will save you from additional `Count` checks:

```
    result = "Select " + string.Join("or ", ls.Select(l => l = string.Format(langs, l)));
```